# how to give css only the 1st label span?

Tags: html, css

```
<p>
 //span 1
 <span>Profile<br>
   <span>My Name :<br><span class="span-bold">Chinu</span></span>
   <span>Address :<br><span class="span-bold">BBSR</span><br><span>CTC</span></span>
 </span>

 //span 2
 <span>Change Password<br>
     <span>aaaaa</span>
     <span>bbbbb<span>b1111</span></span>
 </span>

 //span 3
 <span>cccccc</span>
</p>
```

I have a lots of span. How can i give padding button 10px only the first label span?

I have tried this code:

p span:parent {
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

Comment: What are you calling "the first label span"? The first child of `p`?

Comment: `span:first-child` would do

Comment: Yes i am calling first label span the first child of p. but there have 3 span of the p child.

Comment: why so many span? Wouldn't be better using a better and semantic markup?

Comment: Unrelated but have you considered using a [dl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) instead? It seems more semantically correct.

Comment: your html code is not valid - missing `</span>`

Comment: Yes added one `</span>`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [`How to Ask`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All span but the inner one's, like this

```css
p > span {
  display: block;        /*  with current markup, this is needed to break line  */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

p > span:before {
  content: '• ';
}
```

```html
<p>
<span>Profile<br>
  <span>My Name :<br><span class="span-bold">Chinu</span></span>
  <span>Address :<br><span class="span-bold">BBSR</span><br><span>CTC</span></span>
</span>
<span>Change Password<br>
    <span>aaaaa</span>
    <span>bbbbb<span>b1111</span></span>
</span>
<span>fsfdfd</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This is coming only the first span. but i have 3 span in the first span label.

Comment: @Chinu Updated with a sample .. is it like that you want?

Comment: `second` and `third` parent span not added padding css. I need all the parent span tag should be `padding-bottom:10px`

Comment: @Chinu Updated sample again ... like that?

Comment: No please check my updated question. I have commented my 3 span.

Comment: @Chinu I updated and my sample do target those exact span's. I added a "dot" to them as well, so you see it is correct. My question is, do you want the space exact where your comments are?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
p span:parent { padding-bottom:10px; }
```

you should try the `first-of-type` selector like so:

```
p span:first-of-type { padding-button:10px; }
```

Please let us know if it worked.

Comment: Please add description to your answer. We are voting to delete this question because of its **length** and **content**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean that you want a padding only in the first child of the immediate children `span`

You could add use `p>span` which selects only the immediate children `span` of the `p` and get the first using `first-child` pseudo class and then select its children (immediate or not)

```
p>span:first-child span {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Your code is perfect but I want only the first label span css. Not other span. But you code coming `padding-bottom: 10px;` in the all span.

Comment: Look my html my parent span(p child) tag having 3 span tag. I need all the 3 span will adding `padding-bottom:10px;` not the child span means `span>span`

Comment: I've updated my code once again. This will add padding to all `spans` that are children of the **first** `span` of the `p`

Comment: Plus, the way I see it, your first (parent) span has 5 span children of which 2 are immediate children. Can you upload a drawing or something in which you mark what exactly you want to have padding?

Comment: Please check question I have commented my 3 span. i need these 3 span padding-bottom:10px;

Answer (score 0):

you can select it in different ways. let's say you want to select from whole page first span simple use

```
span:first-of-type{}
```

now you can make it fit your needs

```
p span:first-of-type{}
```

or if you want only direct child of `p` then use `p > span:first-of-type`
you can also use `p > span:first-child Or p span:first-child`

Answer (score 0):

**use the `>` operator !**
It means immediate children.